# LabVIEW displaying keys in a textbox

Tags: file, dll, configuration, ini, labview

I want to display configuration file keys in a textbox, each key value on a separate line in LabVIEW. Do you know how i could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you want a single text indicator, you can do it like this:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file, all sections from config file and keys for each section. Then use an array indicator to display these keys on separate lines. Here is an example:
[image: example]